# Why does Android change county code when change locale?

Tags: android, android-location, android-phone-call

I am working on an Android application, in the app its has various languages supports and has dialing phone number options. I am facing an issue if I change language then the county code also changed for example from user scenario, A Portuguese lives in US, he changes language in his Android phone to Portuguese then the code also changed to 55. My doubt is why does Android changes the country code when changes locale in device? Is there any way to do this without affecting change county code?
I am using compile version Android 25.

Comment: It changes the country code because that's part of changing the Locale. You should allow people to type in the country code manually, instead of trying to guess it.

Comment: Do not Depend on `Locale` fill Country code manually with a Dialog maybe . You can only give user a hint from `Locale` with pre filled country code .